# Is version 1.8 compatible with 1.8.3 servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I have a hosted Minecraft server through Apex, and my question is does the server have a specific version it runs on, so the latest being 1.8.3, and could I change my profile version to say 1.8 release and have the server recognize it? I want to break through the roof of the nether, and I understand that it is impossible on the 1.8.3 version, so being able to switch my profile to an older version quick to do that, then switch back would be great. Otherwise I could always try the enderpearl trick while just creating a portal on the nether roof.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. Minecraft version 1.8 can connect to 1.8.3 servers.

However, the breaking of blocks (such as bedrock) happens server-side. As such, downgrading to Minecraft 1.8 will not allow you to break through the nether ceiling.

Comment: I tried it just now, and it worked.

Comment: That's a statement, not a source.  You need to provide a source of some sort, or offer proof.

Comment: How exactly do you suppose I would obtain proof of this?

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt screnshots showing you are running 1.8 and that you are logging into a 1.8.3 server. might want to also capture the PC's time display in the screenshot for good mesure

Comment: How would I prove the server was 1.8.3?

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt same why you knew it was a 1.8.3 server that you joined

Comment: Because I started the server...

Comment: Why are we not asking this of the other answer?

Comment: So if you started the server, then you should be able to easily prove a 1.8 client can connect to a 1.8.3 server; you just need screenshots.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this helps, but https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79626245/2015-04-09_19.22.04.png

Comment: As far as I can see, that just shows you playing a client at 1.8. I'm not sure how that proves you're connected to a 1.8.3 server, unless I'm missing something in the screenshot.

Comment: I agree. I don't understand how you expect proof.

Comment: You've got one part of it.  You need to show a screenshot of the server, with the version number, and then your client connecting to it.  That would constitute proof in my book.

Comment: Okay, here's a server screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79626245/Screenshot%20from%202015-04-10%2008%3A36%3A34.png

Comment: I'm going to do some science on this issue to confirm for myself. I have a feeling I'm wrong here. @Frank, you really should be holding me to this same standard too.

Comment: I have just verified this for myself. I was mistaken, and, as such, have deleted my incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

**OK, I UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU MEAN**

First, 1.x users cannot play with 1.y players.
Theese updates are called major updates and a server won't allow users to enter if their current 'Major Update Version' is different from the server one.

After that, you can join servers that have a 1.x.0 with 1.x.y servers and vice versa, because these bug fixing updates din't include new blocks/features and so, for example, you can play in version 1.8 if the server is 1.8.3 and vice versa, but you can't play on 1.8.3 if the server's version is only 1.7.2.

**BETTER TO USE ENDERPEARL TRICK!**